# How to connect KEYPAD-SMALLCALC and LCD

Tags: c, embedded, calculator, keil, lcd

I'm working on calculator project using LM3S316 microcontroller & Keil software

I have some confusion about how can I work with KEYPAD-SMALLCALC

So, my question is :
 how can I use this keypad and initialize it 
 also, how can I represent values and use it 
 finally, how to connect it with LCD

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The KEYPAD-SMALL-CALC is a matrix keypad, meaning you should configure some pins as input and some pins as output.
This is a decent library that i personally have used for a project of mine using a matrix keypad - https://github.com/nimaltd/KeyPad

You should be able to integrate it in your code without too much issues.
In short you have cols and rows. In the example provided the rows are input pins and the cols are output pins. There is a for cycle that is checking for a button press. By default rows are high, once a button is pressed the library checks for a combination between row and col that determinate which button has been pressed.
For configuration pins the easiest way would probably to use software such as "STM32CubeMX" which generates c code with your MCU configuration, you can easily configurate there the matrix keypad rows, cols and decide which pins you should use for the LCD.

Edit : Here is a modified version of the github library i have personally used in a project

source keyboard.c

```
#include "keyboard.h"


//#define   _KEYPAD_DELAY(x)            HAL_Delay(x)


const GPIO_TypeDef* _KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PORT[] =
{
                                                            COL_1_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_2_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_3_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_4_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_5_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_6_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_7_GPIO_Port,
                                                            COL_8_GPIO_Port 
};

const uint16_t _KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PIN[] =
{
                                                            COL_1_Pin,
                                                            COL_2_Pin,
                                                            COL_3_Pin,
                                                            COL_4_Pin,
                                                            COL_5_Pin,
                                                            COL_6_Pin,
                                                            COL_7_Pin,
                                                            COL_8_Pin
};

const GPIO_TypeDef* _KEYPAD_ROW_GPIO_PORT[] =
{
                                                            ROW_1_GPIO_Port,
                                                            ROW_2_GPIO_Port,
                                                            ROW_3_GPIO_Port,
                                                            ROW_4_GPIO_Port
};

const uint16_t _KEYPAD_ROW_GPIO_PIN[] =
{
                                                            ROW_1_Pin,
                                                            ROW_2_Pin,
                                                            ROW_3_Pin,
                                                            ROW_4_Pin
};


KeyPad_t    KeyPad;


//#############################################################################################
void    KeyPad_Init(void)
{
    KeyPad.ColumnSize = sizeof(_KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PIN)/2;
    KeyPad.RowSize = sizeof(_KEYPAD_ROW_GPIO_PIN)/2;
}

//#############################################################################################

uint16_t    KeyPad_Scan(void)
{

    uint16_t key                                =   0;
    uint8_t hold_key                        = 0;
    int int_btn_cnt                         = 0;
    int int_button_state_change = 0;    

    GPIO_PinState int_button_current_state = GPIO_PIN_SET;
    GPIO_PinState int_button_last_state = GPIO_PIN_SET;

    for(uint8_t c=0 ; c<KeyPad.ColumnSize ; c++)
    {

        for(uint8_t i=0 ; i<KeyPad.ColumnSize ; i++)
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin((GPIO_TypeDef*)_KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PORT[i],_KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PIN[i],GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin((GPIO_TypeDef*)_KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PORT[c],_KEYPAD_COLUMN_GPIO_PIN[c],GPIO_PIN_RESET);    

        for(uint8_t r=0 ; r<KeyPad.RowSize ; r++){

            while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin((GPIO_TypeDef*)_KEYPAD_ROW_GPIO_PORT[r],_KEYPAD_ROW_GPIO_PIN[r])==GPIO_PIN_RESET){
                int_btn_cnt++;
                if(int_btn_cnt == _KEYPAD_DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS){
                        key |= 1<<c;                    
                        key |= 1<<(r+8);
                        return key;
                }
            }

            int_btn_cnt = 0;            

        }       

    }

    return key;
}






//#############################################################################################
uint16_t    KeyPad_WaitForKey(uint32_t  Timeout_ms)
{   
    volatile uint16_t   keyRead;
    while(Timeout_ms==0)
    {
        keyRead = KeyPad_Scan();
        if(keyRead!=0)
        {
            KeyPad.LastKey = keyRead;
            return keyRead; 
        }
    }
    uint32_t    StartTime = HAL_GetTick();
    while(HAL_GetTick()-StartTime < Timeout_ms)
    {
        keyRead = KeyPad_Scan();

        if(keyRead!=0){
            KeyPad.LastKey = keyRead;
            return keyRead; 
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
//#############################################################################################
char    KeyPad_WaitForKeyGetChar(uint32_t   Timeout_ms)
{
    char result = 0;
    switch(KeyPad_WaitForKey(Timeout_ms))
    {
        case 0x802:     // ^
            result =  '^';
            break;      
        case 0x804:     // 7
            result = '7';       
            break;  
        case 0x808:     // 7
            result = '8';       
            break;          
        case 0x810:     // 9
            result = '9';       
            break;      
        case 0x820:     // 04
            result =  0xFF;         
            break;              
        case 0x840:     // D+
            result =  0xFE;         
            break;      
        case 0x880: //  M
            result =  'M';      
            break;      
        case 0x401: //  -%
            result =  '-';  
            break;              
        case 0x402: //  +%
            result =  '+';  
            break;      
        case 0x404: //  4
            result = '4';   
            break;  
        case 0x408: //  6
            result = '5';           
            break;          
        case 0x410: //  6
            result = '6';           
            break;      
        case 0x420: //  03
            result = 0xFD;              
            break;      
        case 0x440: //  PRUREP
            result = 0xFC;      
            break;      
        case 0x480: //  STL
            result = 0xFB;          
            break;      
        case 0x201: //  ALT
            result = 0xFA;          
            break;              
        case 0x202: //  CLK
            result = 0xF9;          
            break;      
        case 0x204: //  1
            result = '1';   
            break;
        case 0x208: //  3
            result = '2';           
            break;          
        case 0x210: //  3
            result = '3';           
            break;      
        case 0x220: //  02
            result = 0xF8;                  
            break;      
        case 0x240: // PY1 RA
            result = 0xF7;
            break;
        case 0x101: // C
            result = 'C';   
            break;          
        case 0x102: // VD
            result = 0xF6;  
            break;      
        case 0x104: // 0
            result = '0';       
            break;      
        case 0x108: // .
            result = '.';       
            break;              
        case 0x110: // QTY
            result = 0xF5;      
            break;              
        case 0x120: // 01
            result = 0xF4;      
            break;      
        case 0x140: // PY2PO
            result = 0xF3;          
            break;      
        case 0x180: // TL
            result = 0xF2;      
            break;              
    }   

    return result;

}
```

and the header file keyboard.h

```
#ifndef __KEYBOARD_H__
#define __KEYBOARD_H__

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t     ColumnSize;
    uint8_t     RowSize;
    uint16_t    LastKey;    

}KeyPad_t;

void            KeyPad_Init(void);
uint16_t    KeyPad_WaitForKey(uint32_t  Timeout_ms);
char            KeyPad_WaitForKeyGetChar(uint32_t   Timeout_ms);

#define                     _KEYPAD_DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS                5




#endif /* __KEYBOARD_H__ */
```

You should only configure the const arrays with the ports and pins you are planning to use and use the library like this :

init keyboard at the start of your program:

```
KeyPad_Init();
```

and use it like this

```
uint8_t key = KeyPad_WaitForKeyGetChar(1);      // wait 1 ms
```

key is the value of the pressed key, if you use KeyPad_WaitForKeyGetChar(0) the code will stay here and wait for a key press.

Hope it helps!